# Как получить массив из массив объектов?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив объектов такого формата:

```
data = [
    {
        time: "2.30 p.m.",
        value: ["val1", "val2", "val3"] 
    },
    {
        time: "4.00 p.m.",
        value: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]
    },
    {
        time: "1.00 a.m.",
        value: ["val7", "val8", "val9"]
]
```

Как из этого массива можно получить такой массив:

```
const result = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6", "val7", "val8", "val9"]
```

Пробовал сделать таким образом, но выходит неправильный результат

```
const arr = data.map((item) => {
  return [].concat(...acc.pressureHigh)
})
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
data = [
    {
        time: "2.30 p.m.",
        value: ["val1", "val2", "val3"] 
    },
    {
        time: "4.00 p.m.",
        value: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]
    },
    {
        time: "1.00 a.m.",
        value: ["val7", "val8", "val9"]
    }
];
arr = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc.push(...item.value), acc;
}, []);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного короткий вариант

```js
const data = [
  {
    time: "2.30 p.m.",
    value: ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
  },
  {
    time: "4.00 p.m.",
    value: ["val4", "val5", "val6"]
  },
  {
    time: "1.00 a.m.",
    value: ["val7", "val8", "val9"]
  }
];

const a = data.flatMap(({ value }) => value);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: зачем делать `Object.values` у массива?

Comment: @Grundy Потому что массивы в JS являются объектами.

Comment: а что по твоему возвращает `Object.values`? :)

Comment: @Grundy если верить MDN `возвращает массив значений перечисляемых свойств объекта `.  Мне удалить ответ? Работает же

Comment: Просто `Object.values` с массивом тоже работает.  Массиви же тоже состоят из ключей и свойств

Comment: достаточно убрать лишний `Object.values`. По сути ты из массива хочешь получить массив :) что не особо имеет смысл

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов посмотри просто в консоли что выведет `Object.values` для `data`.  А мистер Гранди хочет сказать, что достаточно `flatMap`.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский обновил, спасибо за замечание

Comment: @Grundy изменил, благодарю